# Using a handlebars helper to render a view isn't working

Tags: ember.js

I am simply trying to render a view using a Handlebars helper. I keep getting a error when the app runs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
```

**Handlebars:**

```
 <script type='text/x-handlebars'>
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type='text/x-handlebars' id="index">
    INDEX
    {{my-component-helper}}
  </script>

  <script type='text/x-handlebars' id="myComponentHelper">
  I'm here
  </script>
```

**JS:**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

Ember.Handlebars.helper('my-component-helper', App.MyComponentHelperView);

App.MyComponentHelperView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName:'myComponentHelper' 
});
```

Here is a JSbin illustrating the issue:
http://jsbin.com/edUm/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the ordering. In your version `App.MyComponentHelperView` is undefined when the code is interpreted. Try this instead:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.MyComponentHelperView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName:'myComponentHelper' 
});

Ember.Handlebars.helper('my-component-helper', App.MyComponentHelperView);
```